# Generalized Sagnac-Wang-Fizeau formula

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

In the paper "Generalized Sagnac-Wang-Fizeau formula" (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.94.063837), the authors A. Ori and E. Avron present a generalized derivation of the Sagnac-type effect.
In their presentation, they wrote the formula:
$$dl'=(dl^2_\perp+\gamma^2dl^2_\parallel)^{1/2}=\frac{\gamma}{\gamma_\perp} dl$$
where
\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}\\
\gamma_\perp&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v_\perp^2}}
\end{eqnarray}

The expression in the middle is obvious, they decompose the motion of $dl$ in the perpendicular and parallel direction. However, they give no derivation for the last expression which does not seem obvious to me.
Does anybody know how to obtain it?